# ajaxtoolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender grid view asp.net

Tags: asp.net, view, grid

can i use ajaxtoolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender  to validate zero rows of a grid view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ValidatorCalloutExtender` to extend a `CustomValidator` that has the logic for validating the zero rows Gridview.

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvGridView" runat="server" Text="0 Rows" Display="Dynamic"
    OnServerValidate="cvGridView_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
<ajaxtoolkit:validatorcalloutextender runat="Server" id="vceGridView"
    targetcontrolid="cvGridView" />
```

Codebehind

```
protected void cvGridView_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = gv.Rows.Count > 0;
}
```